# Determine the derivative of $\arctan$ function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $f'(x)$ for the function:

$f(x)= \arctan(\frac{a+x}{1-ax}))$ , $a\in R$

So this is what I've done:

$f(x) = \arctan x$

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

$x= \frac{a+x}{1-ax}$

$f'(x) =  \frac{1}{1+\frac{(a+x)^2}{(1-ax)^2}}$

$f'(x) = \frac{(1-ax)^2}{(1-ax)^2+(a+x)^2}$

Is this correct?

Comment: You forgot to apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}f=\dfrac{d}{d \frac{a+x}{1-ax}}\left[\arctan\frac{a+x}{1-ax}\right]\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{a+x}{1-ax}\right]=\dfrac{d}{d u}\left[\arctan u\right]\bigg|_{u=\frac{a+x}{1-ax}}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{a+x}{1-ax}\right]$$

$$=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{a+x}{1-ax} \right)^2}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{a+x}{1-ax}\right]$$

EDIT1: Explaining the derivative

$$=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{a+x}{1-ax} \right)^2}\frac{1\cdot(1-ax)-(a+x)(-a)}{(1-ax)^2}=\frac{1+a^2}{(1-ax)^2+(a+x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1+a^2}{(1+a^2)(1+x^2)}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

EDIT2: Explaining $(1-ax)^2+(a+x)^2=(1+x^2)(1+a^2)$
$$(1-ax)^2+(a+x)^2=1-2ax+a^2x^2+a^2+2ax+x^2$$
$$=1+a^2x^2+a^2+x^2=(1+x^2)+a^2(1+x^2)=(1+x^2)(1+a^2)$$

Comment: So I would get $f'(x) = \frac{(1-ax)^2}{(1-ax)^2+(a+x)^2} * \frac{1}{1-ax}$ ?

Comment: Added an edit to my answer. BTW you should not expand expressions unless they become more compact or you get meaningful simplifications.

Comment: Yeah that's a bad habit of mine. I'm having trouble understanding how you simplify the expressions,

Comment: When I try to simplify that, no matter if I use calculator or do it by hand, my answer doesn't come close to being $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ . Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @MrYouthMath I also can't understand how you go from $\frac {1+a^2}{(1-ax)^2 +(a+x)^2}$ to $\frac{1+a^2}{(1+a^2)(1+x^2)}$

Comment: Added an explanation

Comment: @MrYouthMath Ah that makes it clear, now I got it solved!

Comment: @MrYouMath I have to prove the differentiability of this function by definition for a=1  at x=1 . But I'm stuck in here $\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} (\frac{\arctan\frac{2+h}{-h}+\frac{\pi}{2}}{h})$ I don't know how to continue, could you help me ? Thank you alot in return.

Answer (score 2):

$$\arctan\left(\frac{x+a}{1-ax}\right)=\arctan x+\arctan a$$
(give or take a multiple of $\pi$), so
$$\frac d{dx}\arctan\left(\frac{x+a}{1-ax}\right)=\frac1{1+x^2}.$$

Comment: Haha a follow up question is to verify $\arctan\left(\frac{x+a}{1-ax}\right)=\arctan x+\arctan a$ using the result from this exercise

Answer (score 0):

you must use the chain rule: $${1 \left(  \left( -ax+1 \right) ^{-1}+{\frac { \left( a+x \right) a}{
 \left( -ax+1 \right) ^{2}}} \right)  \left( {\frac { \left( a+x
 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( -ax+1 \right) ^{2}}}+1 \right) ^{-1}}
$$
simplified to
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: "must use the chain rule"? I didn't $\ddot\smile$

Comment: ok you didn't but i did

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how you simplify that to $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$